# WebStorm is not importing when I paste in a CDN

Tags: ide, webstorm

Can anybody help me out with this? I create a new project, and then when I paste in a CDN, it doesn't ask me to install these external libraries or anything. It used to work, but now it just stopped working for me. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Download library** action (available on `Alt+Enter`) is still there:

[image]

make sure that **There is no locally stored library for the HTTP link** inspection is enabled in **Settings | Editor | Inspections | JavaScript | General**

Comment: The issue has been fixed. Thank you! :)